# My computer won't boot up

Tags: boot, crash

My computer won't boot up and I get the error messages shown below including the following message:

```
Input/output error  
Filesystem check or mount failed.    
A maintenance shell will now be started.
```

What is going on in this screenshot?

[image]

Comment: @K7AAY Why? How would he copy paste to there? You are suggesting he types it out?

Comment: Could it be a connection problem between the motherboard and the drive?

Answer (score 1):

Do this:

1. Reboot into the GRUB menu.
2. Select the Advanced options for Ubuntu choice.
3. Select a Recovery Mode kernel (doesn't matter which).
4. On the next window that pops up, select `root`.
5. Run `umount /dev/sda1`.
6. Run `fsck -f /dev/sda1`.
7. When that finishes, reboot.

Comment: It wont let me open up the terminal

Comment: @user304467 Are you pressing `ctrl` + `D` in the boot process at all?

Comment: No I haven't done that

Comment: @user304467 OK, try this. Reboot, and at the GRUB menu, choose "Advanced options for Ubuntu". Choose one of the recovery kernels (doesn't matter which). When a window comes up, select the `root` option. Run `mount -o remount,rw /`. Now, run `fsck -f /`.

Comment: @user304467 You put a space between `rw` and `/`?

Comment: Ok so I got it typed in /dev/sda1 is mounted next line says e2fsck: Cannot continue, aborting.

Comment: @user304467 /dev/sda1 is your EFI partition, not Ubuntu. If you don't have any other OSes installed, Ubuntu will be on /dev/sda2

Comment: Typed it in again says the same except now it says above it fsck from util-Linux 2.20.1 e2fsck 1.42.9 (4 Feb 2014)

Comment: @user304467 I don't understand what you're saying there.

Comment: Fsck from util-linux 2.20.1 e2fsck 1 42.9 (4-feb-14)next line /dev/sda1 is mounted next line e2fsck: Cannot continue That's what it says

Comment: `mount -o remount,rw /dev/sda2` gave you that error?

Comment: Run this command to see your available disks. Maybe it's not on sda2: `lsblk -o NAME,FSTYPE,SIZE,MOUNTPOINT,LABEL`

Comment: Sda 931.5G next line sda1 ext4 923.5G next line sda2 1k next line sda5 swap 8 G next line sr0 udf 1.7 G

Comment: So it is sda1, OK. Try running just running `fsck -f /dev/sda1`.

Comment: It's still saying cannot continue aborting same as last time

Comment: @user304467 Can you take a screenshot of the output that `mount -o rw,remount /` produces?

Comment: I'm on my phone I wont let me add a photo to my comments when I typed it gave me a blank line ready for me to type another command

Comment: Good. It worked. Now try the fsck.

Comment: Aborted again ughhh

Comment: @user304467 Try `fsck /`

Comment: Still saying /dev/sda1 is mounted aborting

Comment: OH!. OK. Run `umount /dev/sda1` and then run fsck.\

Comment: Ohhh Zack we got something diff lol this is a big one giv me a minute

Comment: /dev/sda1: Clean, 747865/60530688 files, 85720261/242099200 blocks

Comment: Has it finished?

Comment: That's all it said hasn't changed anything

Comment: Are you back at the prompt, or is it still doing something?

Comment: Its At the prompt

Comment: Try rebooting, then.

Comment: Hey it started up ill log on and see if it works and doesn't crash thanks man I appreciate the time you took helping a Linux noob out

Comment: Great! Glad I could help. Should I edit this into my answer?